# error 'unicode' object has no attribute 'objects' and error lies in code:: publishers = publisher.objects.filter(name__icontains=publisher)

Tags: html, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

When tried to search by publisher or by author,I get this error::   'unicode' object has no attribute 'objects' in webpage   and error lies in code::           authors = author.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=author)   AND        publishers = publisher.objects.filter(name__icontains=publisher).......what am I doing wrong

views.py::

```
def searchadva(request):
    if 'author' in request.GET and request.GET['author']:
        author = request.GET['author']
        if not author:
            error = True
        elif len(author) > 20:
            error = True
        else:
            authors = author.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=author)
            return render(request, 'advsearchresults.html',{'authors': authors, 'query': author})
        return render(request, 'advsearchform.html', {'error': error})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')

def searchadvp(request):
    if 'publisher' in request.GET and request.GET['publisher']:
        publisher = request.GET['publisher']
        if not publisher:
            error = True
        elif len(publisher) > 20:
            error = True
        else:
            publishers = publisher.objects.filter(name__icontains=publisher)
            return render(request, 'advsearchresults.html',{'publishers': publishers, 'query': publisher})
        return render(request, 'advsearchform.html', {'error': error})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

models.py

```
class publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

advsearchresults.html

```
    {% if books %}           
        <p>Found {{ books|length }} book{{ books|pluralize }}.</p>
        <ul>               
            {% for book in books %}               
            <li>{{ book.title }}</li>               
            {% endfor %}              
        </ul>   

    {% elif authors %}
        <p>Found {{ authors|length }} author{{ authors|pluralize }}.</p>
        <ul>               
            {% for author in authors %}               
            <li>{{ author.author }}</li>               
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

    {% elif publishers %}
        <p>Found {{ publishers|length }} publisher{{ publishers|pluralize }}.</p>
        <ul>               
            {% for publisher in publishers %}               
            <li>{{ publisher.name }}</li>               
            {% endfor %}  
        </ul>
    {% else %}           
        <p>No books matched your search criteria.</p>       
    {% endif %}
```

error i get when i do search by publisher and same happens but author when done search by author.book search works fine.::-

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/home/prashant/Desktop/lms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
                response = get_response(request)
              File "/home/prashant/Desktop/lms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
              File "/home/prashant/Desktop/lms/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
              File "/home/prashant/Desktop/lmsnew/src/profiles/views.py", line 123, in searchadvp
                publishers = publisher.objects.filter(name__icontains=publisher)
            AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'objects'
            [11/Apr/2018 18:18:13] "GET /searchadvp/?publisher=w HTTP/1.1" 500 74830
```

I dont know what am I doing wrong.PLEASE HELP!

Comment: What is `publisher`? You obviously expect it to be an object with the attribute `objects`, but in reality it is an object of type `unicode`. What you should do is either use a debugger or insert print/log statements in your `def searchadvp(request):` function so that you can see **exactly** what `publisher` is. It is almost certainly not what you expect it to be, and this will point you towards what the solution should be.